# c program deals with multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading

I need help with my c program, I have most of it done but it has some issues.

The program is about ** *Exploring Synchronization Among Processes and Threads.***

You are given three (3) processes in one program that work together to solve a producer consumer problem:

- 2 processes are “producers” and each process produces its own type of product in a continuous loop. That is, one product type produced by one producer and a different product type by the other producer.
- One Process is a “consumer” of products and consist of five (5) threads:

  - 1 thread is a ‘distributor’ thread
  - two (2) threads consume one type of product (ex. consumes only product type 1)
  - two (2) threads consume a second type of product (ex. consumes only product type 2).

The consumer process contains two (2) product storage buffers, each comprised of a fixed number of slots. The number of slots in the buffers are to be different (one has more slots than
the other). You choose and specify the number of slots in each buffer as a definition in your
program solution
Communication between the producer processes and the consumer process is to be through a
single “pipe”. This single, shared pipe is used to communicate between each producer process
and the consumer process. Each producer process writes into this pipe the product to be
consumed by the consumer process.

Final program delivery: completion of the product consumer threads, output file design and
write functions; sample data runs with output files

I have most of it done but it has some issues.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE1 20
#define BUFFER_SIZE2 30

typedef struct
{
    int count;
    int productType;
} product;

int count = 0;
int fd[2];

pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t cond;

typedef struct
{
    product *values;
    int head;
    int tail;
    int numEntries;
    int size;
} queue;

queue q1;
queue q2;

void producer(int args);
void *consumer(void *args);
void *distributor(void *args);
void initQ(queue *q, int size);
bool QEmpty(queue *q);
bool QFull(queue *q);
bool put(queue *q, product prod);
product get(queue *q);

// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6zkaJFjUbM
// https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-c-2/
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // Creating 5 threads 4 consumer and 1 distributor
    pthread_t th[5];
    // Creating our pipe, fd[0] is read end, fd[1] is write end
    if (pipe(fd) == -1)
    {
        perror("error creating pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initializing both buffers
    initQ(&q1, BUFFER_SIZE1);
    initQ(&q2, BUFFER_SIZE2);

    int pid1;
    int pid2;
    int consId1 = 1;
    int consId2 = 2;

    // Initializing lock
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

    // Initialziing condition variables
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);

    // Create first producer process using fork(), child process 1
    if (pid1 = fork() == 0)
    {
        producer(1);
    }
    // Create second prodcuer process using fork(), child process 2
    else if (pid2 = fork() == 0)
    {
        producer(2);
    }
    // Create distrubtor and consumer threads, parent process
    else
    {
        // Creating 4 threads using for loop and pthread_create
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            // 2 consumer threads for product type 1
            if (i == 1 || i == 2)
            {
                if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &consumer, &consId1) != 0)
                {
                    perror("Error creating thread");
                }
            }
            // 2 consumer threads for product type 2
            else
            {
                if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &consumer, &consId2) != 0)
                {
                    perror("Error creating thread");
                }
            }
        }
        // use pthread_join to wait for preivous thread to terminate
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (pthread_join(th[i], NULL) != 0)
            {
                perror("Error joining thread");
            }
        }
        // Distributor thread
        close(fd[1]);

        while (1)
        {
            product prod;

            // Using lock and condition variable around crit section to avoid race condition
            // pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            // pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
            // Read from the pipe
            read(fd[0], &prod, sizeof(prod));
            if (prod.productType == 1)
            {
                put(&q1, prod);
            }
            else
            {
                put(&q2, prod);
            }
        }
        // pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        // pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        // Close read end of the pipe
        close(fd[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Creating the producers
void producer(int args)
{
    int prodCount = 0;
    product prod;
    prod.productType = args;

    // Close read end of the pipe
    close(fd[0]);

    while (1)
    {
        prodCount++;
        prod.count = prodCount;
        // Send product to the pipe so the consumer can use
        write(fd[1], &prod, sizeof(prod));
        // Sleep for 0.01 - 0.2 seconds after each loop
        int time = (rand() % (200000 - 10000 + 1)) + 10000;
        usleep(time);
    }

    // Close write end of the pipe
    close(fd[1]);
}

void *consumer(void *args)
{
    int consCount1;
    int consCount2;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    product prod;
    int prodType = *(int *)args;

    while (1)
    {
        if (prodType == 1)
        {
            get(&q1);
            consCount1++;
            fprintf("Thread ID: %d\n", prodType);
            fprintf(fp, "Product Type: %d\n", prod.productType);
            fprintf(fp, "Production Sequence #: %d\n", prod.count);
            fprintf(fp, "Consumption Sequence #: %d\n", consCount1);
        }
        else
        {
            get(&q2);
            consCount2++;
            fputs("Thread ID: 2\n", fp);
            fprintf(fp, "Product Type: %d\n", prod.productType);
            fprintf(fp, "Production Sequence #: %d\n", prod.count);
            fprintf(fp, "Consumption Sequence #: %d\n", consCount2);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyX30WVuEos&t=196s
// Circular buffer
void initQ(queue *q, int size)
{
    q->size = size;
    q->values = malloc(sizeof(product) * q->size);
    q->numEntries = 0;
    q->head = NULL;
    q->tail = NULL;
}

// Checks if the queue is empty
bool QEmpty(queue *q)
{
    return (q->numEntries == 0);
}

// Checks if the queue is full
bool QFull(queue *q)
{
    return (q->numEntries == q->size);
}

// Used for adding products to the queue
bool put(queue *q, product prod)
{
    // If the queue is full we can not add to it
    if (QFull(q))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Add product to the end of the queue
    q->values[q->tail] = prod;
    q->numEntries++;
    // Move index of the tail
    q->tail = (q->tail + 1);
    // If index goes out of bounds set back to 0
    if (q->tail >= q->size)
    {
        q->tail = 0;
    }
    return true;
}

// Used for removing products for the queue
product get(queue *q)  
{
    product result;

    // If the queue is empty we can not dequeue anymore
    if (QEmpty(q))
    {
        perror("Error on dequeue");
    }

    // Remove from the head of the queue
    result = q->values[q->head];
    q->head = (q->head + 1) & q->size;
    q->numEntries--;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `C` and `C++` are different languages. Tag only the language your code is written in(related to).

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: `if (pid1 = fork() == 0)`?!?!?!  Who is teaching you that?  Just another example of why cramming assignments into `if()` statements is horribly bug-prone.  Use two lines and you won't have bugs like that:  `pid1 = fork(); if ( pid1 == 0 )...`

Comment: Please edit your _question_ and add a description of the expected operation and what you're actually getting. Just saying "it has some issues" isn't descriptive enough. What is the issue? (e.g.) `fork` doesn't work as expected? threads don't join properly? queue has race conditions? No `wait` calls, so zombie processes are created? Pipe `close` calls done incorrectly? Your code does does _not_ compile: `fprintf("Thread ID: %d\n", prodType);`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to revise the code to make it more readable since now it's quite hard to understand.

Here I point out some issues of your code that lead to errors:

1. if condition `if (pidN = fork() == 0) {...}`

you should fork() first and then check the pid:

```
 int pidN = fork();
 if (pidN == 0) {...}
```

2. fprintf() function `fprintf("Thread ID: %d\n", prodType);`

either write the function fputs or fprintf:

```
fputs("Thread ID: \n", fp);
```

or

```
 fprintf(fp, "Thread ID: %d\n", prod.productType);
```

3. Parameter of the fprintf() function: pay attention to the variable you're passing since `prodType` does not exist.