# c program about multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading

- The product type should be 1 or 2 depending on the process that created the product
- product id should increase by one each time one is produced
- consumer id will always be 1,2,3, or 4 depending on which thread consumer consumes the product
- consumer count will increase by 1 each time one is consumed

And product type should only be 1 or 2

i think i need  to change the code up a bit and add condition variables and locks .But stuck at that

I have most of it done but it has some issues.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE1 20
#define BUFFER_SIZE2 30

typedef struct
{
    int count;
    int productType;
} product;

int count = 0;
int fd[2];

pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t cond;

typedef struct
{
    product *values;
    int head;
    int tail;
    int numEntries;
    int size;
} queue;

queue q1;
queue q2;

void producer(int args);
void *consumer(void *args);
void *distributor(void *args);
void initQ(queue *q, int size);
bool QEmpty(queue *q);
bool QFull(queue *q);
bool put(queue *q, product prod);
product get(queue *q);

// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6zkaJFjUbM
// https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-c-2/
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // Creating 5 threads 4 consumer and 1 distributor
    pthread_t th[5];
    // Creating our pipe, fd[0] is read end, fd[1] is write end
    if (pipe(fd) == -1)
    {
        perror("error creating pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initializing both buffers
    initQ(&q1, BUFFER_SIZE1);
    initQ(&q2, BUFFER_SIZE2);

    int pid1;
    int pid2;
    int consId1 = 1;
    int consId2 = 2;

    // Initializing lock
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

    // Initialziing condition variables
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);

    // Create first producer process using fork(), child process 1
    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0)
    {
        producer(1);
    }
    // Create second prodcuer process using fork(), child process 2
    pid2 = fork();
     if ( pid2== 0)
    {
        producer(2);
    }
    // Create distrubtor and consumer threads, parent process
    else
    {
        // Creating 4 threads using for loop and pthread_create
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            // 2 consumer threads for product type 1
            if (i == 1 || i == 2)
            {
                if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &consumer, &consId1) != 0)
                {
                    perror("Error creating thread");
                }
            }
            // 2 consumer threads for product type 2
            else
            {
                if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &consumer, &consId2) != 0)
                {
                    perror("Error creating thread");
                }
            }
        }
        // use pthread_join to wait for preivous thread to terminate
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (pthread_join(th[i], NULL) != 0)
            {
                perror("Error joining thread");
            }
        }
        // Distributor thread
        close(fd[1]);

        while (1)
        {
            product prod;

            // Using lock and condition variable around crit section to avoid race condition
            // pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            // pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
            // Read from the pipe
            read(fd[0], &prod, sizeof(prod));
            if (prod.productType == 1)
            {
                put(&q1, prod);
            }
            else
            {
                put(&q2, prod);
            }
        }
        // pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        // pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        // Close read end of the pipe
        close(fd[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Creating the producers
void producer(int args)
{
    int prodCount = 0;
    product prod;
    prod.productType = args;

    // Close read end of the pipe
    close(fd[0]);

    while (1)
    {
        prodCount++;
        prod.count = prodCount;
        // Send product to the pipe so the consumer can use
        write(fd[1], &prod, sizeof(prod));
        // Sleep for 0.01 - 0.2 seconds after each loop
        int time = (rand() % (200000 - 10000 + 1)) + 10000;
        usleep(time);
    }

    // Close write end of the pipe
    close(fd[1]);
}

void *consumer(void *args)
{
    int consCount1;
    int consCount2;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    product prod;
    int prodType = *(int *)args;

    while (1)
    {
        if (prodType == 1)
        {
            get(&q1);
            consCount1++;
            fputs("Thread ID: \n", fp);
            fprintf(fp, "Product Type: %d\n", prod.productType);
            fprintf(fp, "Production Sequence #: %d\n", prod.count);
            fprintf(fp, "Consumption Sequence #: %d\n", consCount1);
        }
        else
        {
            get(&q2);
            consCount2++;
            fputs("Thread ID: 2\n", fp);
            fprintf(fp, "Product Type: %d\n", prod.productType);
            fprintf(fp, "Production Sequence #: %d\n", prod.count);
            fprintf(fp, "Consumption Sequence #: %d\n", consCount2);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyX30WVuEos&t=196s
// Circular buffer
void initQ(queue *q, int size)
{
    q->size = size;
    q->values = malloc(sizeof(product) * q->size);
    q->numEntries = 0;
    q->head = NULL;
    q->tail = NULL;
}

// Checks if the queue is empty
bool QEmpty(queue *q)
{
    return (q->numEntries == 0);
}

// Checks if the queue is full
bool QFull(queue *q)
{
    return (q->numEntries == q->size);
}

// Used for adding products to the queue
bool put(queue *q, product prod)
{
    // If the queue is full we can not add to it
    if (QFull(q))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Add product to the end of the queue
    q->values[q->tail] = prod;
    q->numEntries++;
    // Move index of the tail
    q->tail = (q->tail + 1);
    // If index goes out of bounds set back to 0
    if (q->tail >= q->size)
    {
        q->tail = 0;
    }
    return true;
}

// Used for removing products for the queue
product get(queue *q)
{
    product result;

    // If the queue is empty we can not dequeue anymore
    if (QEmpty(q))
    {
        perror("Error on dequeue");
    }

    // Remove from the head of the queue
    result = q->values[q->head];
    q->head = (q->head + 1) & q->size;
    q->numEntries--;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What issues?  Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: What is the question?  "stuck" is a statement (of fact).

Comment: i mentioned it above .But it writes wrong pattern in .txt file

Comment: The product type should be 1 or 2 depending on the process that created the product
    product id should increase by one each time one is produced
    consumer id will always be 1,2,3, or 4 depending on which thread consumer consumes the product
    consumer count will increase by 1 each time one is consumed

And product type should only be 1 or 2

Comment: You asked the same thing an hour ago: [c program deals with multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74464440/5382650) Please don't reask questions that are essentially the same. Edit your [original] question to add details. And, as I mentioned in your original question, you said: "it has some issues". You've repeated that here without any further explanation. People there and here have asked "What issues?" and you've not responded.

Comment: Your consumer process (the parent process) creates a queue, and it creates four threads that are supposed to read from the queue, but then it joins those same four threads before it ever puts anything in to the queue. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: Your consumer process joins the four `consumer()` threads, but you have not provided any way for the `consumer()` function to ever return. What's the point of `join()`ing it in that case? and what's the point of putting any code after the `join()` calls?

Comment: Your `put(Q, value)` returns a boolean value to indicate success or failure (Q full). But the call site never tests the return value. Likewise, `get(Q)` prints a message if the queue is empty, but the caller has no way to know that the call failed.